# React Native force fullscreen keyboard in landscape

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-textinput

I have a simple TextInput in my react-native Android app and I basically need to bring the fullscreen editing mode when focused on the keyboard while in landscape mode. As from what I've read, the system may automatically adjust this if needed. However I need to always force this keyboard view in landscape mode:

[image: fullscreen keyboard android]

There are not much information about this on the docs. There is only a prop [disableFullscreenUI](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#disablefullscreenui-android).

```
<TextInput
    disableFullscreenUI={false}
```

I tried using that, but the docs already mentions: *"the OS may choose to have the user edit the text inside of a full screen text input mode"*. I need to force show this view, not let the OS decide.

It can be solved by building a new screen and binding it to onFocus however I would like to know if someone has experienced this and there's a smarter way rather than a workaround.
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you find any workaround for this?